# Conversion failed,when using AutoQuery in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I have the following AutoQuery function.

```
[Route("/cars/search")]
public class SearchCars : QueryDb<Car, CarDto>
{
    public List<int> EquipmentIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> ManufacturerIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> ColourIds { get; set; }
}
```

The function works, when I do the following:

Cars/Search?ColourIds=1&format=json

Cars/Search?ManufacturerIds=1&format=json

but when I try to use

Cars/Search?EquipmentIds=1&format=json

I get "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '[1]' to data type int.".

The difference between these fields is that Car object can have multiple EquipmentIds, but only one ColourId and ManufacturerId.

```
public class Car
{

    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Colour Colour { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ColourId { get; set; }

    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<Equipment> Equipment { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<int> EquipmentId { get; set; }

}
```

Do I have to define for which attribute the different parameters should be assigned too?

Comment: Shouldn't `EquipmentId` in `Car` be `EquipmentIds`?

Comment: I changed this because of the join would not work if it was named EquipmentIds. I changed it back, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) works by constructing an RDBMS query based on [implicit conventions](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#queries-on-collections) which is used to construct an SQL query that runs on the RDBMS.

Complex Types in OrmLite data models are blobbed by default which means they can't be queried in the RDBMS with SQL, so you wont be able to query it with AutoQuery.

You could create a hybrid [Custom AutoQuery Implementation](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations) where you can apply any custom logic to filter the results of the AutoQuery results, something like...

```
public class MyQueryServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    //Override with custom implementation
    public object Any(SearchCars query)
    {
        var equipmentIds = query.EquipmentIds;
        query.EquipmentIds = null;
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, base.Request);
        var response = AutoQuery.Execute(query, q);
        if (equipmentIds != null)
            response.Results.RemoveAll(x => x.EquipmentId...);
        return response.
    }
}
```